# Automated server security testing best practices?

Tags: penetration-test, automation

Is there a standard way of automatically testing the basic security of my web server? I've found a couple on-line services, (e.g. http://hackertarget.com/), and they seem ok, but I'd like to start off with the basics. Is there a go-to method for stress-testing a web server's security?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of scanners out there which aren't free. Like Nexpose or Nessus which can do way more than just scanning a webserver. But they provide this functionality as well of course.

The interesting part is that these scanners can also log into your server and perform configuration reviews to a certain standard. For instance the DISA STIG is a very good baseline to test against and see if you have properly implemented your webserver in a secure way.

Aside from that, you can also test the application itself, with automated scanners like Burp or Appscan.

Another option would be to use [ASV](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/approved_companies_providers/approved_scanning_vendors.php). They are normally only used for PCI-DSS compliance, but you can also use them of course even if you needn't be compliant with PCI-DSS. Their baseline scans and reports are a very good baseline assessment to see what the level of security is, as the PCI-DSS requirements are not light at all.

Comment: There is a [Nessus Home edition](http://www.tenable.com/products/nessus-home).

Comment: @Gumbo true, but it can't be used for commercial purposes though. Although the OP didn't specify this.

Comment: There is [OpenVAS](http://www.openvas.org/) which is an open source fork of Nessus.

Comment: yea but that's what his current solution is using.